# how to solve my problem of conversion of string to datetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to list dates in the dropdown list, but I am having a conversion problem in the **GenreLst.AddRange command (GenreQry.Distinct ());** can someone help? thanks
I tried use **Convert.ToDateTime()** but not work.

```
public ActionResult Index(string startData)
    {
        var GenreLst = new List<string>();

        var GenreQry = from d in db.Programa
                       orderby d.Data_Registo
                       select d.Data_Registo;
        
        GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct()); //Error string
        ViewBag.startData = new SelectList(GenreLst);

        var datas = from m in db.Programa
                     select m;
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(startData))
            return View(datas);
        else
        {
            DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(startData);
            return View(datas.Where(x => x.Data_Registo == start));
        }
    }
```

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP4Vb.png)

```
CS1503:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.lQueryable<DateTime?> to System.Collections.Generic.lEnumerable<string>'
```

Comment: Don't store dates as strings to begin with. All databases have date-related types like `datetime` or `date`

Comment: Normally there would be an error message to go with the squiggly red line. It would greatly increase your chances of getting a useful answer if you were to include that error message as text in your question.

Comment: As for an error - you didn't post one. Just a picture with squigglies. Images can't be copied, compiled and tested. What's the actual error you get? Perhaps the query returns a proper `DateTime`? Why not store it in a `List<DateTime>` ?

Comment: If you're storing `Data_Registo` as a DateTime in the database then you'll need to convert these values to a string to be able to add them to your list of strings. `GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct().Select(b => b.ToString("yy-MM-dd")));`

Comment: my data (Data_Registo) is with DateTime but I want to load it as a string

Comment: @Miguel Error message?

Comment: Question is...why do you want a list of strings? Why not pass DateTime objects to the view? It's really the view's job to deal with the visual formatting of the data I'd say, rather than the controller's. There's no need to turn a date into a string until the moment you want to display it to a human being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to append a list of type `DateTime?` to a list of type `string` which is causing the error you are seeing here.

To resolve this you could declare `GenreLst` to be of type `List<DateTime?>` such as:

```
var GenreLst = new List<DateTime?>();
```

Which would then allow you to append `GenreQry`.

Alternatively could declare `GenreLst` as the result from `GenreQry.Distinct()`:

```
var GenreLst = GenreQry.Distinct();
```

Comment: Yes it works. sometimes it seems that I just complicate the simple :) thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
   public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(object dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        DateTime tvParsedDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTime.ToString(), out tvParsedDate))
        {
            return tvParsedDate;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This appears to have nothing at all to do with the question being asked (although since you didn't bother to add any explanation of your code, we've no idea what logic you are applying with your answer). Did you post this in the wrong place by accident?